# Get the page number and page size

Tags: c#, asp.net, jsgrid

I need to get the page size and page number of the **jsgrid**. Based on the page number, i need to get the records from DB. Because when I use above 100k records, jsgrid got stuck and its loading for a long period.

How to get the page number of the jsgrid?
And also I want to get the search text and pass it to cs method. I don't want filter inside the jsgrid by using

```
loadData: function (filter) {
    return $.grep(clients, function (client) {
        return (!filter["fieldname"] || client["fieldname"].toLowerCase().indexOf(filter["fieldname"].toLowerCase()) > -1) )}
```

It is filtering the data which is loaded in jsgrid. I want to pass the search text to cs.

to get the data to bind in jsgrid,(serializing the data)

```
  DataTable dtItem = // get the data from the DB foreach 
    (DataRow row in dtItem .Rows) 
    {
     gridList += "{'Id':" + row["ID"] + ",'Name': '" + row["NAME"] + "'}, ";
    }
```

to search,need to get the data from the filter area and pass it along with the pagenumber to the sql procedure.

Answer (score 1):

**You** decide on page size you want in the `jsGrid` options, example:

```
$("#table").jsGrid({
  ...
  paging: true,
  pageSize: 10, //eg 10 rows per page
  pageLoading: true,
  ...
```

With the above options, the grid will show the paging controls, ie the links that allow the user to navigate to next/previous page or jump to a page.

When `pageLoading` is true, the `filter` parameter in the `loadData` method will have two members, example:

```
filter: { pageSize: 10, pageIndex: 2 }
```

`filter.pageIndex` is determined by which navigation link the user clicks. You should then use these two parameters to shape your database query accordingly to return only `pageSize` rows for the `pageIndex`<sup>th</sup> page (counting from 0).

Your `loadData` method must not return the whole data table! If you are using Microsoft SQL Server, you can easily return only the rows for a page with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 OFFSET pageSize*pageIndex ROWS FETCH NEXT pageSize ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Do you know how to use Ajax?  How do you load your data currently (assuming it is not too many rows)?

Comment: Can you show your existing code where you get the data for the grid.  That is the part that has to be modified to do paging.

Comment: DataTable dtItem = // get the data from the DB
 foreach (DataRow row in dtItem .Rows)
   {
           gridList += "{'Id':" + row["ID"] + ",'Name': '" + row["NAME"] + "'}, ";
    }

Comment: And for search , get the string and retrieve the data based on the search string and load based on the paging.